# MySQL trigger not updating table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

This code is very similar to my problem. I'm not sure why Table A is not updated at all. I `SELECT * FROM A` at the end and A remains empty. I've been at this for hours and I can't figure out why my trigger is not working. Thanks

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
aVariable int
);

CREATE TABLE B
(
bVariable int
);

delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER AB
AFTER INSERT ON B
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.bVariable < 10) THEN //I also tried bVariable < 10
       INSERT INTO A VALUES (11)
    END IF;
END;

delimiter ;

INSERT INTO B VALUES (1);

SELECT * //A is still empty
FROM A;

SELECT *
FROM B;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the correct syntax for comments. See [9.6 Comment Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comments.html).

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS B;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS A;

CREATE TABLE A (
  aVariable int
);

CREATE TABLE B (
  bVariable int
);

DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER AB AFTER INSERT ON B
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 -- IF (NEW.bVariable < 10) THEN //I also tried bVariable < 10
    IF (NEW.bVariable < 10) THEN -- //I also tried bVariable < 10
       -- INSERT INTO A VALUES (11)
       INSERT INTO A VALUES (11);
    END IF;
END//

DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO B VALUES (1);

--  SELECT * //A is still empty
SELECT * -- //A is still empty
FROM A;

SELECT *
FROM B;
```